# Is it possible to combine more than 2 CompletableFuture in Java 8/11?

Tags: java, completable-future

I am reviewing the operator *.thenCombine* from *CompletableFuture*, but I have some issues when I try to combine more than 2 *CompletableFuture* objects.

**Example:**

```
CompletableFuture<List<String>> completableFuture =
        CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> fetch.andThen(log).apply(url1))
        .thenCombine(CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> fetch.andThen(log).apply(url2)),
        //.thenCombine(CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> fetch.andThen(log).apply(url3)),
        (s1, s2) -> List.of(s1,s2));
        //(s1, s2, s3) -> List.of(s1, s2, s3));
```

When I try to add the third *CompletableFuture*, I receive an Error in *IntelliJ*.

Any feedback?

Many thanks in advance

Juan Antonio

Comment: receive an Error in IntelliJ, what error?

Comment: You can use `allOf()` to combine any number of `CompletableFuture`, followed by a `thenApply()` stage in which you inspect the individual futures using `join()` on each (they will be guaranteed to have successfully completed).

Comment: The message from Intellij is: "Incopatible parameter types in lambda expression" Source: https://github.com/jabrena/latency-rosetta-stone/blob/758d3bd2b79e2aabd2c88b1f5e84ea0c4117ed72/java/src/main/java/org/fundamentals/latency/LatencyProblem01.java#L135-L149

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it this way:

```
future1.thenCombine(future2, Pair::new)
        .thenCombine(future3, (pair, s3) -> List.of(pair.getKey(), pair.getValue(), s3));
```

You can also encapsulate it in a separate function:

```
public static <T1, T2, T3, R> CompletableFuture<R> combine3Future(
        CompletableFuture<T1> future1,
        CompletableFuture<T2> future2,
        CompletableFuture<T3> future3,
        TriFunction<T1, T2, T3, R> fn
) {
    return future1.thenCombine(future2, Pair::new)
            .thenCombine(future3, (pair, t3) -> fn.apply(pair.getKey(), pair.getValue(), t3));
}
```

Where `TriFunction` is:

```
@FunctionalInterface
public interface TriFunction<T, T2, T3, R> {
    public R apply(T t, T2 t2, T3 t);
}
```

And use it this way:

```
combine3Future(future1, future2, future3, (s1, s2, s3) -> List.of(s1, s2, s3));
```

Comment: Yes but this is my question, out of the box, it is not possible, it is necessary to use this workaround. Many thanks